# Schema Upgrades and last_modified attribute (GAE & NDB)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've just finished setting up the foundations for performing schema upgrades on GAE's datastore using mapreduce. We're using NDB and many or our models utilise the auto_now keyword option to DateTimeProperty to set a last_modified attribute.

```
last_modified = ndb.DateTimeProperty( auto_now=True )
```

Of course, on running the mapreduce job which updates entities the last_modified attribute is updated as well which is not really what we want.

```
def upgrade_entity(entity):
    # modify entity
    yield op.db.Put(entity)
```

According to the docs you can override the value for a property with auto_now_add set, but not with auto_now.

I'm now thinking there may well be other circumstances where we don't want the last_modified attribute to be updated as well.

So, is there any way to preserve the entity's last_modified value or do we add another property or replace these properties with one's we can control and just set the values manually?

---

ok, so the consensus seems to be that I should be able to define an alternate version of the model which is only used by the mapreduce code, not the user facing code (I very much want to avoid having to shut down the site to do a schema upgrade) but I haven't been able to get this to work.

With the following setup the user facing code works properly (updates last_modifed) until I run mapreduce which also works properly (doesn't update last_modified). After running mapreduce the user facing code no longer updates last_modified..

models.py

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):
    # model used by user facing code
    last_modified = ndb.DateTimeProperty( auto_now=True )
```

upgrade.py

```
class MyTmpModel(ndb.Model):
    # model used by mapreduce code
    @classmethod
    def _get_kind(cls):
        return 'MyModel'
    last_modified = ndb.DateTimeProperty( auto_now=False )

def upgrade_model(entity):
    # mapper function 
    # modify entity
    yield op.db.Put(entity)
```

mapreduce.yaml

```
mapreduce:
- name: Upgrade Model
  mapper:
    input_reader: mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader
    handler: upgrade.upgrade_model
    params:
    - name: entity_kind
      default: upgrade.MyTmpModel
```

---

ok, I'm going put my issues here down to the fact that I have been testing this in dev_server and the differences in the way things run there compared to the real gae server. I've concluded that in dev_server all the code is running in the same process and the different model versions are not getting along.. from the NDB model docs:

> An application should not define two model classes with the same kind, even if they live in different modules. An application's kinds are considered a global "namespace".

I'll assume that I can rely on the fact that on the real gae server the mapreduce code will run in separate instances and these version clashes will not occur and it will not affect the user facing server instances so the setup above should work as expected.

Thanks Tim & Guido for your help.

cheers,

J

Comment: You could add a version where auto_now is not set to True and run your mapreduce against that version.  It doesn't give you the fine grain control you want, but would probably be the simplest way during your schema migration.

Comment: thanks, Tim. You make it sound simple, so maybe it is.. and that should also apply to making the model a subclass of Expando for removing attributes.. so now I'm thinking I can just define the temporary version of the model somewhere and use that in the mapreduce config as long as it has the same class name as my actual model? (learning more about how Python works every day.. and GAE and NDB..)

Comment: hmm.. ok, for the record, defining my "temporary" version of the model alongside my mapper function and referencing it in the mapreduce config worked great but then when I went into my app and modified the entity the last_modified property was not updated so it seems the "temporary" version of the model overwrites my real version in the app too. Unfortunately this means that anyone using the app will be using the "temporary" version of the model..

Comment: and renaming the model class and overriding it's _get_kind method to return the actual model's kind doesn't work either. ie it does work, but it overrides the model definition used by the app when you run the mapreduce job.

Comment: Have the mapreduce code import a different version of the model class that doesn't include the auto_now  Then the user facing code has the correct behaviour by importing the correct version

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't appear to be the case. Before running the mapreduce the user facing code behaves properly (updates last_modified). Running mapreduce behaves properly (doesn't update last_modified). But after running mapreduce the user facing code no longer updates the last_modified unitl the server is restarted (testing on dev_appserver).

Comment: THen you are doing something wrong, note Guido;s answer is the same as mine.  If the user facing code doesn;t work after running mapreduce it means the user facing code is using the same model.  Also you didn't mention you are using dev server.

Comment: hmm.. the user facing code knows nothing of my new tmp model.. I'll do a test on the gae server..

Comment: thanks again, I've added my conclusion to the original question..

Comment: PS. Don't add your answer to the question; it is perfectly fine to answer your own question!

Comment: I have tried with ndb allow access their option using like object._properties['lastUpdatedOn'].auto_now = False so you can disable temporary auto_now but not tried with db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set auto_now=False in all your model definitions in the map/reduce code.

My suggestion for doing this with the least chance for errors:

Define a global constant that can be True or False which you use for all the auto_now settings in your model definitions.  Then you have to change only that one line to change it from True to False for all models.  You can even make it compute the value automatically based on some environment variable.

Comment: thanks Guido. So where could I set an env var that would differentiate between user facing code and mapreduce code? Where and when would the computation be done? (I've added my tmp model attempt to my original question)

Comment: Actually I'm thinking that you're using the same *version* of your app for your map/reduce as for the regular code? Don't do that, they will be mixed up. Instead, deploy your mapreduce job as a different version (just edit app.yaml). Then you can check for the version in the environment, e.g. os.getenv('CURRENT_VERSION_ID').split('.')[0]